# How to Stable My Postfix against Spams or Virusses

Tags: centos, postfix, update

I'm managing dedicated. In last days my server Ip is blocked by hotmail services. And my customer can't send any message to hotmail/live/outlook systems.

```
postfix ver: 2.6.6
CentOS 6.4 64 Bit
I just Installed MailScanner and Clamd latest version
```

And these are my open relay report:

```
Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx

220 mail.domain.com ESMTP Postfix [1451 ms]
EHLO please-read-policy.mxtoolbox.com
250-mail.domain.net
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN [780 ms]
MAIL FROM: <supertool@mxtoolbox.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok [889 ms]
RCPT TO: <test@example.com>
454 4.7.1 <test@example.com>: Relay access denied [780 ms]
QUIT

SendSMTPCommand: You hung up on us after we connected. Please whitelist us. (connection lost)

MXTB-PWS3v2 5351ms
```

> ## postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
delay_warning_time = 4
disable_vrfy_command = yes
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = all
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost $mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = mydomain.net
myhostname = mail.mydomain.net
mynetworks = all
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination reject_non_fqdn_sender reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_unknown_recipient_domain
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/mail.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/mail.key
soft_bounce = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_maps.cf,                     regexp:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/virtual_regexp
virtual_gid_maps = static:12
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/zpanel/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/zpanel/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 101
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:101
```

Comment: What does your postfix version have to do with Hotmail not accepting your mail?

Comment: `Postfix 2.6.6`

My IP is in hotmail block list. They said me "your ip is in block list cause Symantec BrightMail Filter reported your IP"

Comment: That has nothing to do with your version of Postfix.

Comment: I thought old version has security problems. And latest version must be more secure than version 2.6.6. And postfix 2.6.6 no longer supported by postfix.org. `ftp://ftp.pca.dfn.de/pub/tools/net/postfix/index.html`

Comment: thx @MichaelHampton

Comment: I added the report. @MichaelHampton

Answer (score 1):

Not supported since this year means not a risk. I think security fixes get backported from the CentOS maintainers.

Your mailing problem is normally a bad configured server. Do a open relay test, and configure your server to not send spam. If it doesn't get better, your server is compromised.

Comment: I Just installed MailScanner with ClamAV. I think this will be fix the problem

Comment: If your server is bad configured, no mailscanner will help. do a open relay test, and fix your config

Comment: Thx @Pazi I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to upgrade postfix-2.6.6. It stable (legacy release) version of MTA. All you need is to analyze your mail log file and configure more restrictive rules in main.cf. I would suggest to install and configure some policy service, for e.g. [policyd](http://www.policyd.org/), [postfwd](http://postfwd.org/). You can get more info [here](http://www.postfix.org/addon.html#policy)

It would be great if you add thу output of `postconf -n` to the question

Comment: thx @Alex_hha I added

Comment: I looked at [link](http://www.senderbase.org) no black list

Comment: mynetworks should be 127.0.0.0/8

Comment: thak you @ALex_hha